# How can I switch to a ViewController or TableViewController with a parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

var newsListView: UIViewController!

newsListView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsList")
        sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(newsListView)

Comment: Can you give more context around your question? I don't understand what you want to know or why.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
var newsListView: UIViewController!
var newsTableView: UITableViewContoller!

if iwantlistview == true {
    newsListView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsList") sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(newsListView)
} else {
    newsTableView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsTable") sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(newsTableView)
}
```

I hope this helps :)